# How to remove password help from passwordbox in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, passwordbox

I'm using a passwordbox control in a UWP app. By default it shows an eye icon with the help of which user can see the password to know if he typed it correctly or not.

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="UwpApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"   />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Although I'm targeting my application for windows 10 but I want to get rid of this password showing capability as per my applications requirement

Interestingly, this password showing capability is absent from the [passwordbox control available for WPF applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.passwordbox?view=netframework-4.7.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `PasswordRevealMode="Hidden"` in the `PasswordBox`

[PasswordBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_PasswordBox_PasswordRevealMode)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.passwordrevealmode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_PasswordBox_PasswordRevealMode